# undefined local variable or method `f' for , when partial rendering with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI5id.png)

When click button.. the partial has to display.

```
$('#info_fields').html( '<%= render partial: "investor_info_fields", locals: { f: f } %>');
```

partial form.

```
<%= f.fields_for :investor_infos do |f| %>
            <div class="nested-fields">
              <%= f.label :name %> <br>
              <%= f.text_field :name, label: "invested companies", class: "input-md form-control mb-20" %>

               <%= f.label :investment_size_id, "Investment size" %> <strong> *</strong><br>
              <%= f.collection_select :investment_size_id, InvestmentSize.all, :id, :size, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20 startup_info_required"} %><br>


              <%= f.label :investment_time_id, "Investment time" %> <strong> *</strong><br>
              <%= f.collection_select :investment_time_id, InvestmentTime.all, :id, :time, {}, {class: "input-md form-control mb-20 startup_info_required"} %><br>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".my-class").click(function() {
               var whut=$(this).val();
               ($(this).val() == 4) {

               $('#info_fields').html( '<%= render partial: "investor_info_fields", locals: { f: f } %>');

        }
          });
```

image:

Comment: Where have you written this script? If it is outside form_tag, it won't work. You need to write it inside form_tag.

Comment: kkk.. i written outside of main form tag.

Comment: I suppose you have this in any ajax request. This f should be form object. and should be in form.

Comment: Same error getting... i written inside form tag only. Added jquery  code .. in quetion

Comment: @GaneshRaju this won't work as i can see that you dn't have `f` local variable in `script` block. can you illustrate what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry.. i didn't get error now. But, partial not rendering when click on button.

Comment: um ... where is the `.my-class` element supposed to be located?

Comment: @Ganesh Raju. f is local variable and you are trying to pass out of scope that's why this error occur. So make sure to set f object in scope.

Comment: @max pleaner .my-class is located within main form only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to make following two changes:

1. As I have mentioned in comment, If you have written the script
   within form_tag, it won't work. So shit your script within form_tag.
2. Replace following line:

   `$('#info_fields').html( '<%= render partial:
   "investor_info_fields", locals: { f: f } %>')`

   with:

   `$('#info_fields').html( '<%= j render partial:
   "investor_info_fields", locals: { f: f } %>')`

Here I have added a `j` (a.k.a. escape_javascript) in front of `render` keyword which help you to render the partial from javascript, if there is some ruby code inside the partial, other than simple html code.

Comment: Thank you .. now it working. I forget put  if statement. But duplicate fields are rendering. means.. first time its perfect but, if click second time same fields are rendering two times.....

Comment: For this, can you please attach a screenshot with your question?

Comment: screenshot.. attached

Comment: Two things. First: Image in not being displayed in the post. I have to access it by seeing the edit. Second: Please explain a bit more, as the image do not have duplicate fields.

Comment: I also added image but, not displayed. Thank you @Vishal.  problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that @GaneshRaju. Also you may share the solution that you came up with.